# React Native WebRTC TypeError

Tags: javascript, react-native, webrtc, react-native-webrtc

I don't understand how to properly import components from webrtc into a project file without errors.
When importing the lines:

```js
import { RTCPeerConnection, RTCIceCandidate, RTCSessionDescription, RTCView, mediaDevices } from 'react-native-webrtc';
```

both from all components and a single component gives an error:

> ERROR TypeError: Superexpression must be either null or a function,
> engine js: hermes ERROR Invariant Violation: "main" was not
> registered. This can happen if:
>
> - Metro (local dev server) is running from the wrong folder. Check if Metro is running, stop it and restart it in the current project.
> - Module failed to load due to an error and `AppRegistry.registerComponent` was not called., js engine: hermes

Solutions taken:

- reinstalling the library
- project rebuild
- restart Metro

Ideally, nothing else can influence this error, because exactly the same error occurs if you build a clean project with only this library and try to import it.

I will be very grateful for your help. I am trying to solve the problem for the second day. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're using the latest version of webrtc, and it's not fully compatible for some reason, you need to downgrade the version. Use `npm i react-native-webrtc@1.75.3`